# Oracle Sql - conditional table join on columns value

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, conditional-statements

I have a table called Stores. 
I need to join this table with another table called Security.

I need to join only if the column Enabled of Security table is set to Y. 
Joining condition: Stores.ID = Security.ID 
Only when Security.Enabled = 'Y'.

How to do that?

Comment: Are you certain that the join condition is `Stores.ID = Security.ID`?  That sounds wrong...

Comment: Thats the design. Security ID is the same as Store ID

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic `SELECT ... WHERE` statement:

```
Select   S.*
From     Stores   S
Join     Security Y  On S.Id = Y.Id
Where    Y.Enabled = 'Y'
```

You could alternatively put the condition in the `ON` clause (but in the case of an `INNER JOIN` it is effectively the same):

```
Select   S.*
From     Stores   S
Join     Security Y  On  S.Id = Y.Id
                     And Y.Enabled = 'Y'
```

Comment: I need all the data from Stores, if the Enabled is 'N'. If its Y, it might show some data from Security table too.

Comment: That's a different question entirely - I've updated the answer to only pull from the `Stores` table, but it sounds like you're wanting something else...  If you have a different question, you'll need to post a new question.

Comment: What do you mean by "it *might* show some data from Security". So what is the rule to show some data?